# Problem authenticating users with Laravel8 and LDAPRecord

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, ldap

I'm working on a Laravel 8 project that logs a user in through one of two Active Directory servers using LDAP Record 2.5 with a Users table in my DB (MySQL 8) just to have access to some basic info like name, email and a unique user id.

I got the initial part working - I get a successful login to the AD and my users table gets automatically synced with the Active Directory data. If I do a dd() right after the auth()->attempt() I will get what looks like a normally initialized User model and the relevant row in the users table has its remember_token field filled in.

But regardless of whether I pass a remember parameter or not there is no actual authentication - calling auth()->user() or Auth::user() returns a null anywhere except for the login method itself and the debug toolbar doesn't show a user model.
This is the code of my custom LoginController:

```
public function store(Request $request)  {
        $credentials = [
            'mail' => $request->input('username').'@pio.rs',
            'password' => $request->input('password'),
        ];
        $remember = ($request->input('remember') == true) ? true : false;
        auth()->shouldUse('pio');
        if (auth()->attempt($credentials, $remember)) {
            dd(auth()->user()); //returns working user model here
            return redirect()->route('home');
        } else {
            auth()->shouldUse('voj');
            if (auth()->attempt($credentials, $remember)) {
                return redirect()->route('home');
            }
        }
    }
```

And these are the settings in my config/auth.php file:

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'pio',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
'guards' => [
        'voj' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'voj',
        ],
        'pio' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'pio',
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'voj' => [
            'driver' => 'ldap',
            'model' => App\Ldap\Voj\User::class,
            'database' => [
                'model' => App\Models\User::class,
                'password_column' => false,
                'sync_attributes' => [
                    'email' => 'mail',
                    'name' => 'cn',
                ],
                'sync_existing' => [
                    'email' => 'mail',
                    //'operator' => 'ilike',
                ],
            ]
        ],
        'pio' => [
            'driver' => 'ldap',
            'model' => App\Ldap\Pio\User::class,
            'database' => [
                'model' => App\Models\User::class,
                'password_column' => false,
                'sync_attributes' => [
                    'email' => 'mail',
                    'name' => 'cn',
                ],
                'sync_existing' => [
                    'email' => 'mail',
                    //'operator' => 'ilike',
                ],
            ]
        ],
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution - just needed to call the auth middleware with `middleware(['auth:pio,voj'])` instead of just `middleware(['auth'])`